# mysql select case multiple columns as

Tags: mysql

I want to set multiple fields with something like this, how can I make it work?

```
Select TableId,
    CASE
        WHEN StartTime > Appt THEN
            Field AS Field_1
            FieldId AS FieldId_1
        WHEN StartTime BETWEEN Appt AND DATE_ADD(Appt, INTERVAL 1 MONTH) THEN
            Field AS Field_2
            FieldId AS FieldId_2
    END
FROM TableA;
```

It doesn't work, the syntax is wrong near AS Field_1.

Comment: You didn't say what's bad with what you did

Comment: And where are your `SET` statement?

Comment: Is your intention that your case statement produce two extra fields or four extra fields?  You have four different names being produced.

Comment: Want 2 fields, just don't want to evaluate the condition for each field, would rather do the condition once, then apply it to many fields.

Comment: Can you explain more about what you want to accomplish?  It looks like you want to change the column alias depending on the selected data. That's not possible because not all the rows will satisfy the same conditions in the `CASE` statement. The query result has to have just one column alias name for each column for all rows.

Answer (score 7):

You're trying to perform something similar to macro expansion in a SQL statement, which you cannot do. The simplest way to solve your problem is to write the SQL dynamically in your application code, and execute that statement conditionally from the app.

If you must do it within SQL, you have a couple of options.

Each `CASE` is a single expression, so you can only produce output fields singly, by having a separate `CASE` for each column:

```
SELECT ID,
  CASE WHEN StartTime > Appt THEN Field_A 
       WHEN StartTime BETWEEN Appt AND DATE_ADD(Appt, INTERVAL 1 MONTH) THEN
        Field_B
  END AS field1,
  CASE WHEN StartTime > Appt THEN Field_C 
       WHEN StartTime BETWEEN Appt AND DATE_ADD(Appt, INTERVAL 1 MONTH) THEN
        Field_D
  END AS field2
FROM TableA;
```

Alternatively, use the [statement form of `CASE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/case.html) (or [`IF`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/if.html), which might be simpler) within a stored procedure, to contain multiple versions of your statement and execute them conditionally.

Answer (score 2):

That is utterly broken `case` syntax. If all you're doing is changing the aliases of those fields, then do that transformation in your client.

e.g.

```
SELECT (StartTime > Appt) AS case1,
       (StartTime BETWEEN Appt AND Appt + INTERVAL 1 MONTH) AS case2
       Field,
       FieldID
FROM TableA

if ($row['case1']) then
    $field_1 = $row['Field'];
    $fieldid_1 = $row['FieldID'];
} else if ($row['case2']) {
    etc..
}
```

Comment: This is part of an inner query to I can't do that.

Answer (score 1):

change the order of your field selection, 
because case should be first column to be retrieved with alias in mysql
the code should be as follows

```
Select 
    CASE
        WHEN StartTime > Appt THEN
            Field AS Field_1
            FieldId AS FieldId_1
        WHEN StartTime BETWEEN Appt AND DATE_ADD(Appt, INTERVAL 1 MONTH) THEN
            Field AS Field_2
            FieldId AS FieldId_2
    END as <alias>,
TableId
FROM TableA;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are close, it looks like this

```
Select TableId,
    CASE WHEN StartTime > Appt THEN Field   ELSE NULL END AS Field_1,
    CASE WHEN StartTime > Appt THEN FieldId ELSE NULL END AS FieldId_1,
    CASE WHEN StartTime BETWEEN Appt AND DATE_ADD(Appt, INTERVAL 1 MONTH) THEN Field ELSE NULL END AS Field_2 ,
    CASE WHEN StartTime BETWEEN Appt AND DATE_ADD(Appt, INTERVAL 1 MONTH) THEN FieldId ELSE NULL END AS FieldId_2

FROM TableA;
```

Comment: But its running that condition once for every field, I want it to run it once and apply it to many fields.

Comment: The way you suggest is essentially what I am currently doing.

Comment: @Raymond - then the answer is no, you can't do it in SQL

Answer (score 0):

I dont know what is `field_XXXX` content,

But i can make it work with reusing the switch case from the query like this one :
(here i am using `temporary variable`)

```
SELECT TableId,
    CASE
        WHEN StartTime > Appt THEN
            @temp := 'Field_1' 
        WHEN StartTime BETWEEN Appt AND DATE_ADD(Appt, INTERVAL 1 MONTH) THEN
            @temp := 'Field_2' 
    END AS `Field`,
    CASE
        WHEN @temp := 'Field_1' THEN 'FieldId_1'
        WHEN @temp := 'Field_2' THEN 'FieldId_2'
    END AS `FieldId`
FROM TableA;
```

maybe this what you mean.

Comment: Assigning values to variables and using them within the same query is a big no no in MySQL because as per the docs you may get unexpected results.