# How do I pass a user variable (@variable) as a column name in a select statement?

Tags: mysql, parameter-passing, user-variables

Here is my table:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kPj5m.png)

My statement is returning this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kXKuw.png)

But I want it to return this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9r3ZG.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mWA8Y.png)

Comment: You have to use dynamic sql for this https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-prepared-statements.html

Comment: Use `CASE` to select the column you want, based on `@columnname`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47094290/378779